# Please Help Me Rollback My Google Docs to the Old Version

Tags: google-docs

In 2010, I created a Google doc using CSS style and Edit HTML features.  This Google doc is a very detailed Specification for one of my projects, and I have spent so much time styling it and making it look perfect.

However, in 2011, I found Google Docs prompted to upgrade to the new version.  I made a copy of the document and tried it out, and it really *disappointed* me.  So I kept to use the old version.

A week ago, when I opened the document, it was in the new version *without* my permission, and all my CSS styles were gone, and I could not edit CSS/HTML any more.  The revision history is also gone!!!

Please help me rollback to the old version.

Answer (score 2):

Goto File -> See Revision History. You should be able to change back to your old revisions from there.

[image: revision history]

[image: revision list]

Comment: No, I cannot do that. All revisions are also gone.